# PHP Remove all after particular pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove all characters after a particular pattern from a string (url). Following are some example urls.

```
http://www.example.com/profile/aaa-bbb/Group
http://www.example.com/profile/ccc-ddd/Group?tab=23
http://www.example.com/profile/Group-sss-t/Group
http://www.example.com/profile/ppp-qqq/
```

I need the output as,

```
http://www.example.com/profile/aaa-bbb/
http://www.example.com/profile/ccc-ddd/
http://www.example.com/profile/Group-sss-t/
http://www.example.com/profile/ppp-qqq/
```

Here actually i need to remove all characters after `Group`, but in the third utl there `Group` is present twice. Dont know how to handle this. Help please, thanks in advance

Comment: You could try to find the first index of `Group` and then trim the string to that length.

Comment: You never explain the *pattern* you want to use. Please explain *exactly* how to figure out what should be retained, and what should be removed.

Comment: I m pointed out `Here actually i need to remove all characters after Group, but in the third utl there Group is present twice.` this is the problem...dont know how to handle when there is two occurances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick ( removes everything after the last / )

```
$newUrl = preg_replace('/(.*)\/.*$/', '$1/', $url);
```

See: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j7c-8gx and hit F9 to see the result of url: 'http://www.example.com/profile/ccc-ddd/Group?tab=23'

Comment: I do not have to explain myself, but I will: A simple `strrpos` and `substr` would suffice here. Using a regular expression is overkill.

Comment: Downvotes are pointless without explanation. But thank you for clarifying. Not that I agree though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but got an output as `http:/`

Comment: Ah yes. I made a mistake in my regular expression. Its fixed now, try again.

Comment: `preg_replace() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given`

Comment: `preg_replace('/(.*)\/.*$/','$1/', $url)`

Comment: Check: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j7c-8gx for a working example (hit the run button (F9)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I disagree, compared to a simple regex, strrpos/substr for stuff like this is a bitch to read and maintain, so i'd say screw the extra CPU cycles spend on compiling a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would use strrpos witch finds the position of a substring but starts from the end:

```
if(strpos($url,"Group")!==false){
    $url = substr($url,0,strrpos($url,"Group"));
}
```

Comment: but if the url is like this one `http://www.example.com/profile/ccc-ddd/Group?tab=23&Group=12`. Is it works...? The urls are inputs from the users. I need to extract taht...

Comment: Nope then it wont work, it would result in: http://www.example.com/profile/ccc-ddd/Group?tab=23&

Answer (score 0):

```
%(http://www.example.com/profile/[^/]+/)%
```

Matches *http://www.example.com/profile/* followed by one of these groups.

So `preg_match_all('%(http://www.example.com/profile/[^/]+/)%', $urls, $matches)` saves the matched parts in `$matches`.